# inode parameter in driver open

Tags: linux, unix, kernel, linux-device-driver

Today, I started thinking about inode structure passed in "open" call to device drivers in linux. I have religiously used "inode->i_rdev" for major and minor numbers before. But I never used it for any other purpose. ( Most probably I never went past my toy drivers.)

So, I was wondering if some one can explain any other usage of this structure inside device driver. (Is it kept as part of legacy?)

Thanks

P.S. : Does this structure have any relation to inode structure maintained by file systems? It  is kind of confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The dev_t word simply is the major/minor number of the device in question.  It has no other purpose I'm aware of.  This is like asking "what other uses does tv_usec have in struct timespec?".  Fields store what they're designed to store.

Comment: If I understand the question right, agent.smith asks about the uses of 'struct inode'.

Comment: Eugene got it. I wanna know is there any other purpose of inode structure other than major and minor number.